# Who do I make CSS development suggestions to?

Tags: css

I've got what i think it a useful idea for CSS development but I'm unsure where to make my suggestion or to whom it should be directed.

Is there a universal inbox for CSS improvement suggestions at the W3C? I know it will take forever to get suggestions drafted, tested and put into the CSS specs but there is no time like the present...

Comment: CSS is a markup language for specifying style. What does that have to do with a universal inbox? I can't see the connection.

Comment: i don't know the answer, but i'm realy curious about whats you idea - would be nice if you could explain something (and the reactions here will show you if it 's a good idea... maybe you don't even have to buck up wich the bask of fineding someone official ;) )

Comment: @Asaph - try rereading the question....

Comment: are you sure its not part of the next CSS spec? hmmm...

Comment: The idea was for a different unit (of height). Have you ever found it annoying to set heights in pixels, %, em's and the like? My idea was to set height by the number of lines (of text content). Example... element { height: 2lines; }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The W3C has a [Participation FAQ](http://www.w3.org/participate/faq) that you might be interested in, but if your idea is development-related, does it really need to be a part of the specification? Or is it the sort of thing that developers of popular (CSS-related, web development) tools could simply add support for?
Rather than going directly to the W3C, I'd suggest first trying to get some more exposure for your idea. Write up a blog post describing it, submit it to some popular sites like [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/), [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com), or [Reddit](http://reddit.com/) -- basically, get as many eyes on your idea as you can.
If your suggestion really is a good one, it'll help to gain momentum by getting a lot of attention. Or, if it's a bad idea, you'll quickly find out by having people "review" it. You'll likely get some good suggestions to improve the idea, and you'll definitely spend your time better getting peer feedback than somehow trying to singlehandedly champion it to the W3C.